# Fixed content on Image - PDF content - php or css?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, jpeg

I have a problem with position of content. I do have a jpg image with header and footer (little image on header and some words on footer)... If I have big content, for 2 pages, my words go in my first page footer, and in the 2nd page header over it. How can I detect to set that footer and header to be fixed even if it's a image. or to make content to be exactly fixed for one or more pdf page to don't go over my footers and headers.

Comment: are you talking about a web page or a pdf?

Comment: I have a page. After i click on a button it download me a pdf with a big content. That pdf is created with a image backgorund that have a header and footer. I want to put my content between that pdf/image footer-header.

Comment: where is the code generating the pdf?

Comment: And *what* is it?  I've used mpdf and done str_replace on the stylesheet name in the HTML prior to render time ...  and you may want to look into page-break-before in CSS ....